# Работа функции std::time()

Tags: c++, c

Что будет с функцией `std::time(0)`, когда количество секунд, прошедших с 1970 года превысит максимально возможное хранимое число в возвращаемом типе?

Comment: Будем надеяться, что за оставшиеся 20 лет все жизненно-важные (например, управляющие электросетями) старые (т.е. те в которых тип `time_t` имеет 32-разряда) 32-разрядные системы будут обновлены...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Циклический перенос :) - уйдет в нуль.

Только ведь теперь `time_t` - 64-битный, насколько я помню... А за 290 миллиардов лет или C++, или Земля, или человечество - но кто-то точно пропадет...

В Visual C++ 2015

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[])
{
    cout << "sizeof(time_t) = " << sizeof(time_t) << endl;
    cout << "typeof(time_t) = " << typeid(time_t).name() << endl;
}
```

дает

```
sizeof(time_t) = 8
typeof(time_t) = __int64
```

Comment: Прелесть `time_t` в том, что когда придёт время, реализации компиляторов увеличат его разрядность, как это уже произошло ранее `32->64`, хотя запас 32-битной реализации ещё есть до 2038

Comment: Кстати, за секунду до того, как он уйдёт в нуль, он вернёт флаг ошибки `(std::time_t)(-1)`

Comment: @vp_arth а каким образом они увеличат разрядность?

Comment: Новым стандартом :)

Comment: Откровенно говоря, чуть по другому. Через 20 лет (Tue Jan 19 06:14:07 2038) 32-разрядный `time_t` станет **отрицательным** (кстати, если кто вдруг не знает, то `time_t` это signed тип), а вот обнулится он (и пойдет на второй круг) через 89 лет. Аналогично и для 64-разрядного (через 292 млрд. лет он тоже станет отрицательным, а вот обнулится через 584.5 (для справки, возраст нынешней вселенной оценивается в 13,81 миллиарда лет))